# Did the young boy move the broom through the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

At the end of *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*, the three young children are speaking a different language. They are interrupted by the alien and one boy goes outside.

When he picks up the broom, it looks like he didn’t actually touch it and the broom came to him.

Comment: Yes, he brooms with the Force.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, he is sensitive to the Force.

It might indicate that a whole new generation of Jedi is out there. Among those three young children you saw talking, that boy was telling the legend of Luke Skywalker. After being told by that alien, he goes outside and moves the broom near to wall via the Force.

From Archieve.org Cache of [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/20171212192746/https://www.bleedingcool.com/2017/12/12/star-wars-the-last-jedi-spoilers) **[Warning: this article contains spoilers]**

> **A New Generation is Born:** The final scene of the movie shows boy retelling the legend of Luke Skywalker until he is yelled at to go work. He walks outside and very casually moves a broom an inch from the wall into his hand proving he is Force sensitive. We see him looking up at a ship shooting through the stars and we see him with the ring on his finger. A new generation of Jedi and rebels are out there and ready.

Comment: Thank you! I watched it at the midnight release and at that part in the film I was tired so wasn’t sure if it was my imagination! Thanks for that link too!

Comment: Expanding on your answer: Snoke proposed a theory where Rey's force "awakened" because of Kylo becoming stronger (keeping the balance). Since Snoke just died, maybe the young force-sensitive kid will eventually join the dark side? (obviously he has a resistance ring, but Anakin went bad, maybe the kid will too)

Comment: The Jedi religion just died out with the last of it's holy texts burned. We will need to redefine "going bad".

Comment: google cache is broken. Also... I think everything in that sentence is wrong @mathreadler

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I have updated the link.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek try and convince me it is not intended as a feature.. :)

Comment: heh. I would but *spoilers* :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems this character was added to enforce the fact that blood line means nothing in terms of the force/jedi (similar to Rey's heritage)

Comment: I think Kylo Ren's motives/true beliefs aren't yet clear and thus I'm not sure if we can trust his intent towards Rey. Is he doing everything he does for his own benifit or is he still following the beliefs of Snoke, despite what happans between characters? With another film left, I think there are some things we should reserve until we have more definative proof of what the nature of things are.

Comment: @DarthLocke I thought the rules of the Sith was that there would only be two. With Rey in the picture both Snoke and Kyle Ren couldn't be alive. So I thought he killed Snoke so Kylo Ren and Rey could rule together as a pair. That's what I thought anyway... So he's still following Snoke's goal, but not Snoke.

Comment: Kylo Ren and Snoke are not Sith. There can be Force Users that are neither Jedi or Sith and/or splinter groups. In Aphra comic, we learn of a Jedi splinter group called Ordu Aspectu whose leader, Rur, found a way to artifically preserve his conscious in a kyber crystal, but it became corupt. Maz Kanata is a [light-sided] force user whose not a Jedi. There are multiple views on the force and it seems TLJ is testing the waters with this as well, although I suspect IX will be more definative on those matters. Here's what Abrams said though about Snoke and Ren: https://moviepilot.com/posts/3741527

Comment: @Albzi - The rule is that there is one Apprentice and one Master, but it's been established within canon that an Apprentice can also be a Master to another Apprentice (such as Sidious -> Dooku -> Assajj Ventress).  This also lines up with the Jedi Master/Padawan relationship (Kenobi -> Anakin -> Ahsoka Tano).  Also to Darth Locke's point, they technically aren't Sith, they just follow a similar structure.

Comment: Yes and No. It's true that the pretense of Rey Rising and the quick demies of a would be somebody (Snoke) would lean towards that conclusion. However this is still about how an outsider saves a lineage (one snoke believed to be important for an yet to be disclosed reason), as Rey moves Luke to help her and help Liea and because of the unclear destiny and/or relationship to Kylo Ren--but possibly to try and save him, if possible. It's about both the skywalker lineage and outsiders.